# Why can't we find wccp on 3550 cisco L3 switch?

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, switch

I'm trying to use wccp (Web Cache Communication Protocol) on 3550 cisco switch, the problem is that I can't find `wccp`:

I can't do this command:

```
switch(config)#ip wccp ....
```

or

```
switch#sh ip wccp
```

it seems that wccp is not defined, Why? and How can I define it?

I have seen a tutorial that tells:

> In order to enable WCCP redirection in the Catalyst switch, you need
>   to issue the sdm prefer extended-match command (and reboot the
>   switch). By issuing the show sdm prefer command, you are able to see
>   the actual configuration of the TCAM/ASIC Hardware in the switch.

so I did the following:

```
Switch(config)# sdm prefer routing extended-match
Switch(config)# exit
Switch# reload
```

but nothing worked!

Comment: Short answer: it doesn't support WCCP.  cisco.com/go/fn Look up the version of IOS running on your switch.

Comment: can I update the version of IOS to support WCCP @RickyBeam

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to Feature Navigator you can use IOS image c3550-i5k2l2q3-mz.121-19.EA1.bin or c3550-i5q3l2-mz.121-19.EA1.bin for WCCPv2 on the 3550.

[image: Cisco Feature Navigator - WCCPv2 / 3550]

Comment: It wasn't showing anything last night. And it might be an EMI vs. SMI thing (which cannot be changed.)